# How to use dynamic location for godotenv.Load() .env file?

Tags: go, environment-variables, go-testing

### Problem

I am building a REST API in Go. The [godotenv package](https://github.com/joho/godotenv) is used to load the environment variables. Running `go run main.go`, the project runs the API as expected, the environment variables are loaded.

However, when wanting to run the test using: `go test ./...` - which runs `config/config_test.go` among others - it throws the following error: `Error loading .env file` (as specified in function).

**Given the following project structure:**

```
> app
> auth
> config
  - config.go
  - config_test.go
> migrations
> static
> vendor
- .env
- .gitignore
- docker-compose.yml
- go.mod
- go.sum
- main.go
- README.md
```

In **config.go**,  I use the following function to load the Database configuration.

```
func GetConfig() *Config {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file")
    }

    dbHost := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    dbPort := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    dbName := os.Getenv("DB_DATABASE")
    dbUsername := os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME")
    dbPassword := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")

    return &Config{
        DB: &DBConfig{
            Connection: "mysql",
            Host:       dbHost,
            Port:       dbPort,
            Username:   dbUsername,
            Password:   dbPassword,
            Name:       dbName,
            Charset:    "utf8",
        },
    }
}
```

I understand that it works when running from root, because the `.env` resides in root. When running `config/config_test.go`, it tries to look for the `.env` file in the `/config/.env`. If I change the line: `err := godotenv.Load(".env")` to `err := godotenv.Load("../.env")`, the config_test.go runs successfully, but the `go run main.go` from root does not run successfully.

### Question

How can I load the `.env` location dynamically from the `GetConfig()` function in `config.go`, so that both the `go test ./...` and `go run main.go` can load the `.env`?

**Edit**

I am aware that passing a `path string` parameter to the `GetConfig()` function would work in my application (I am initializing this config in the app package). However, I want to create multiple tests in different directories, and prefer not to pass a parameter. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Pass the file location into `GetConfig`. Then in `main.go` pass `.env`, and in your test, pass `./testdata/.env` or whatever.

Comment: That is indeed a valid solution and I have considered it, likewise as a simple if statement in case loading fails. It will work in most cases since I have a App module that holds the config as well. However, I am planning on creating tests that will work individually of that initialization. I was hoping for a solution without having to pass parameters or creating if statements.

Comment: Why do you not want to rely on passing a parameter? That's the correct solution.  I'm also not sure what you mean by 'creating if statements"... what kinds of if statements would be required?

Comment: There are multiple possible solutions discussed here - https://github.com/joho/godotenv/issues/43

Comment: @Flimzy In case the first if statement fails, try another .env location ad infinitum. Not elegant and still the parameter solution is preferable. I rephrased `not wanting to rely` to `prefer not to`, because I believe there should be another solution and will try one of the [suggested solutions](https://github.com/joho/godotenv/issues/43#issuecomment-503183127) provided by @Inian.

Comment: @inian provided solution on Github did the trick. I have added it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Inian, I implemented the following solution, also listed on the `Issues` tab of the [godotenv package](https://github.com/joho/godotenv/issues/43#issuecomment-503183127).

In **config.go** I added a constant for the directory name (which is `rest-api` in my case). I added a `loadEnv` function that tries to get the root path of the project dynamically, based on the project name and the current working directory.

```
const projectDirName = "rest-api" // change to relevant project name

func loadEnv() {
    projectName := regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*` + projectDirName + `)`)
    currentWorkDirectory, _ := os.Getwd()
    rootPath := projectName.Find([]byte(currentWorkDirectory))

    err := godotenv.Load(string(rootPath) + `/.env`)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file")
    }
}

func GetConfig() *Config {
    loadEnv()

    dbHost := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    dbPort := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    dbName := os.Getenv("DB_DATABASE")
    dbUsername := os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME")
    dbPassword := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")

    return &Config{
        DB: &DBConfig{
            Connection: "mysql",
            Host:       dbHost,
            Port:       dbPort,
            Username:   dbUsername,
            Password:   dbPassword,
            Name:       dbName,
            Charset:    "utf8",
        },
    }
}
```